A question about the Hoffman-Singleton graph minus a star
The Hoffman-Singleton graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoffman%E2%80%93Singleton_graph) is vertex transitive and has diameter $2$.
So, for any vertex $v$ the subgraph induced by the vertices at distance $2$ from $v$ is the same graph $G$.
This graph $G$ has $42$ vertices.
The vertex $v$ has $7$ neighbors, and each of these neighbors has $6$ neighbors different from $v$, that form an independent set in $G$.
This provides $G$ with a structure of $7$ parts of $6$ vertices each.
Each vertex in a given part has exactly one edge to some vertex in each other part.
There are no edges within a part.
However, the way these vertices are connected seems totally random, no matter how I try to relabel the vertices.
Of course it isn't, but I have been unable to detect any pattern, and trying to google this did not produce any results.
Is anyone able to detect a pattern? Or maybe you can provide a literature reference?
I am looking for a relation like: vertex $i$ in part $j$ is adjacent to vertex $f(i,j,k)$ in part $k$.
EDIT: the best I could do so far is, find a $6\times6$ matrix with entries from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ that describes all edges.
The matrix depends on the chosen vertex labeling.
One example of such a matrix is
Matrix([[0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 0],
        [4, 0, 3, 3, 0, 4],
        [5, 5, 0, 5, 4, 3],
        [2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5],
        [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 1],
        [3, 4, 2, 0, 2, 2]])

As you can see this is not exactly a "nice" matrix.
It is better than listing $126$ edges, but the graph has $S_7$ as its automorphism group, so I am more or less hoping for a better solution.
EDIT: the question seems to be somewhat confusing. An alternative (and simpler) phrasing would be: provide an elegant description of this graph without using the fact that it is a subgraph of the Hofmann-Singleton graph.

What kind of pattern are you looking for? The wikipedia page you mention already has a couple ways one could construct it. In particular, the constructon from pentagons and pentagrams seems intuitive. Also: are you sure this is the graph you are talking about? Since the graph on wikipedia has 50 vertices.

@MatthewSpam I originally had the same confusion - the question is not about the entire Hoffman–Singleton graph but (1) about the 42-vertex subgraph we get by removing a vertex and its neighbors, and (2) with a specific balanced $7$-coloring, which I'm not sure is unique.

@MishaLavrov Indeed the graph is not the entire Hoffman-Singleton graph. It is about Graph 1177 from the House of Graphs: the Hofmann-Singleton graph minus a star. However, I am not looking for a coloring, just for an easy way to describe which edges it has. Since it is $7$-partite, with equal parts, and vertex-transitive with a considerable automorphism group, I had some hope to easily describe which edges it has, based on part index and index of the vertex within the part of the endpoints.

The $7$-partition is the $7$-coloring I am referring to. If you do not actually care about it, then I think it is much easier to avoid it, and give a description that's based on the Hoffman-Singleton construction.

I do care about it. I wish to understand what's going on in the "outer shell".

In that case, you should also specify which $7$-partition you mean. The Hoffman-Singleton graph is actually $4$-partite, so intuitively it seems like we should be able to find many balanced $7$-partitions.

I apologize. I have incorrectly assumed that what is natural to me is also natural for someone else. The problem description has been enhanced.

Here is a self-contained description in terms of the Fano plane, based on the construction from $PG(3,2)$ on Wikipedia.
Begin by choosing a particular labeling of the points in the Fano plane; for example, take $\mathscr F = \{123, 145, 167, 246, 257, 347, 356\}$. We construct the graph $G$ by connecting $7$ independent sets, one for every triplet in $\mathscr F$.
For each triplet $xyz$, the independent set corresponding to it (call it $I_{xyz}$) has $6$ vertices of two different types:

Two of the vertices are permutations of $[7]$: specifically, the permutations written as $(x\;y\;z)$ and $(z\;y\;x)$ in cycle notation.
The other four vertices are the four $3$-element subsets of $[7] - \{x,y,z\}$.

For example, $$I_{123} = \Big\{(1\;2\;3), (3\;2\;1), \{4,5,6\}, \{4,5,7\}, \{4,6,7\}, \{5,6,7\}\Big\}.$$
The rule for connecting the vertices is as follows:

For each permutation-type vertex $(x\;y\;z)$, apply that permutation to the elements of $\mathscr F$ other than $xyz$, and connect $(x\;y\;z)$ to the subset-type vertices obtained in this way. For example, $(1\;2\;3)$ is adjacent to $\{2,4,5\} \in I_{167}$, based on the triplet $145 \in \mathscr F$, and similarly to $\{2,6,7\} \in I_{145}$, $\{3,4,6\} \in I_{257}$, $\{3,5,7\} \in I_{246}$, $\{1,4,7\} \in I_{356}$, and $\{1,5,6\} \in I_{347}$.

We also join two subset-type vertices if they are disjoint: for example, $\{4,5,6\}$ is adjacent to $\{1,2,7\} \in I_{356}$, to $\{1,3,7\} \in I_{246}$, and to $\{2,3,7\} \in I_{145}$, as well as to some permutation-type vertices defined by the previous rule.



Thanks. I had seen the Fano construction for the entire Hoffman-Singleton graph, but failed to recognize that part of it could be used to construct the subgraph.
